# Odin Flash error: SW REV CHECK FAIL : [lk]Fused 2 > Binary 1

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, device-firmware, odin, 8.1-oreo

I've been trying to flash stock ROM on my Samsung J7 Max. Briefly, these are the steps I followed :

1. Enable Developer Options
2. Disable OEM lock
3. Reboot phone and open into Download Mode (Power+Home+Down)
4. Open Odin 3.12 on PC (with latest samsung drivers installed)
5. Connect phone via original data cable
6. Load the four *.tar.md5 files into respective slots (BL,AP,CP,CSC taken from [here](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-j7-max/SM-G615F/INS/download/G615FXXU2BSC1/265325/))

   Until now the message at top in Download Mode is:

   ```
       ODIN MODE (HIGH SPEED)
       PRODUCT NAME: SM-G615F
       CURRENT BINARY: Custom
       SYSTEM STATUS: OFFICIAL
       FRP LOCK: OFF
       OEM LOCK: OFF
       WARRANTY VOID: 0x1 (0x30d)
       MTK SECURE BOOT: ENABLE
       AP SWREV: B2 K0 S0
       SECURE DOWNLOAD: ENABLE
   ```
7. Disable Auto-reboot and Click Start. The process runs for about two minutes and then following two errors occur-

   On the phone: this line is printed-

   ```
       SW REV CHECK FAIL : [lk]Fused 2 > Binary 1
   ```

   On Odin: Here's the complete log:

   ```
   <ID:0/004> Removed!!
   <ID:0/004> Added!!
   <ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1205)..
   <ID:0/004> File analysis..
   <ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
   <ID:0/004> Initialzation..
   <ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
   <ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
   <ID:0/004> SingleDownload.
   <ID:0/004> preloader.img
   <ID:0/004> lk.bin
   <ID:0/004> trustzone.bin
   <ID:0/004> param.bin
   <ID:0/004> efuse.img
   <ID:0/004> RQT_CLOSE !!
   <ID:0/004> 
   <ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed.
   <OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
   ```

Note that this same error happens if I try to upload a random tar file. So it seems an invalid BL file is causing the issue, but I've re-downloaded and verified the md5 hash of the BL file.

Also, I cannot open the recovery mode. Even when FRP Lock is off, the phone is showing a screen similar like this:

[image: Recovery mode not accessible]

The message at the top on this screen says `Rollback version is not matched (md1rom)`. Can anyone explain what this error is?

Before flashing, my phone had Android 8.1 and the firmware was also last updated on 21 Mar 2019 (Android version:  8.1, code: G615FXXU2BSC1).

Edit :
I've also tried to upload individual tar.md5 files to device and found that files other than BL file upload successfully and the above error is generated when I try just the BL file.

Comment: any update?....

Comment: yes. The update is I changed my phone xD